# Simulate keyboard click in GTA:SA

Tags: c#, winforms, sendkeys, intptr

I'm trying to run a program that sometimes will simulate clicks in GTA:SA. Problem is it doesn't do anything when running. I have tried this code so far:

```
IntPtr calculatorHandle = FindWindow(null, "GTA:SA:MP");
if (calculatorHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    MessageBox.Show("GTA:SA:MP isn't running");
    return;
}
SetForegroundWindow(calculatorHandle);
SendKeys.SendWait("T123");
```

I'd be glad if you tell if something is wrong with my code. Thanks!

### EDIT

This is my code after adding Neill's code:

```
IntPtr calculatorHandle = FindWindow(null, "GTA:SA:MP");
if (calculatorHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    MessageBox.Show("GTA:SA:MP isn't running");
    return;
}
SetForegroundWindow(calculatorHandle);
short key = 0x14;
WindowsMessageService.SendKey(key, KeyFlag.KeyDown);
Thread.Sleep(10);
WindowsMessageService.SendKey(key, KeyFlag.KeyUp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that most games make use of DirectX input. You will have to make use of the following to send keys to the game. Also, you would need to send up and down key to simulate the keypress for the game.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MouseInput
{
    public int dx;
    public int dy;
    public int mouseData;
    public int dwFlags;
    public int time;
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct KeyboardInput
{
    public short wVk;      //Virtual KeyCode (not needed here)
    public short wScan;    //Directx Keycode 
    public int dwFlags;    //This tells you what is use (Keyup, Keydown..)
    public int time;
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct HardwareInput
{
    public int uMsg;
    public short wParamL;
    public short wParamH;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct Input
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int type;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public MouseInput mi;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public KeyboardInput ki;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public HardwareInput hi;
}

[Flags]
public enum KeyFlag
{       
    KeyDown = 0x0000,
    ExtendedKey = 0x0001,
    KeyUp = 0x0002,
    UniCode = 0x0004,
    ScanCode = 0x0008
}

public static class WindowsMessageService
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern UInt32 SendInput(UInt32 nInputs,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 1)] Input[] pInputs, Int32 cbSize);

    public static void SendInput(short keycode, KeyFlag keyFlag)
    {
        var inputData = new Input[1];

        inputData[0].type = 1;
        inputData[0].ki.wScan = keycode;
        inputData[0].ki.dwFlags = (int)keyFlag;
        inputData[0].ki.time = 0;
        inputData[0].ki.dwExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero;

        SendInput(1, inputData, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Input)));
    }

    public static void SendKey(short keyCode, KeyFlag keyFlag)
    {
        SendInput(keyCode, keyFlag | KeyFlag.ScanCode);
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
short key = 0x3B; // F1 key

WindowsMessageService.SendKey(key, KeyFlag.KeyDown);

Thread.Sleep(10);

WindowsMessageService.SendKey(key, KeyFlag.KeyUp);
```

Comment: I just tried that with `short key = 0x14;` (T key) but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the pointer to the MainWindow of the GTA process?

Comment: What I have done is the launch the game myself using ProcessStartInfo and Process.Start. The process instance provides the MainWindow property which you must use to SetForegroundWindow before you send the keys.

Or you can use : Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).FirstOrDefault()
to attach to the running process of the game.

Comment: I've edited my post with my new code, is anything wrong in there?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it sorted out. It wasn't working because I run GTA as administrator, so I have to run the program as administrator too. Now my question is if it's possible to send a key sequence from a string. How do I translate the characters to their codes?

Comment: I have a class that provides the mappings but arent at work. To send a string sequence you have to loop thru the chars in the string and send each one individually.

Comment: Is it possible to choose if I want to send the key 'a' or 'A'?

Comment: Yes, but must look at Shift code. I will post the stuff tomorrow if you can wait, otherwise you have to google 